# unable to set value from server-side to a Textbox in client side

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code is like this

```
 <asp:TextBox type="text" name="txtEndDate" Text="<%#library.GetDictionaryItem("ProfilePages_CVR nummer")%>"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Everything looks okay to me, But i don't know why its throwing an error

```
The server tag is not well formed.
```

Comment: Why don't you use `txtEndDate.Text = library.GetDictionaryItem("ProfilePages_CVR nummer");` in code behind file?

Comment: You are not allowed to use <% tag on server controls property. So Please use the option said by satpal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that because of the ASP.net brackets which contain double quotes inside them

```
<asp:TextBox Text="<%# someMethod("someValue") %>" />
```

inside the Text field, you need to use single quotes instead of double quotes on that property, like this:

```
<asp:TextBox type="text" name="txtEndDate" 
    Text='<%# library.GetDictionaryItem("ProfilePages_CVR nummer")%>'  
    runat="server">
</asp:TextBox>
```

And it will work.

Note also that you are using the DataBinding notation ( `<%#` ) which will only work if your TextBox is inside a DataBound control, or you call DataBind on the control or page containing this TextBox.

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes like:

```
<asp:TextBox type="text" name="txtEndDate" Text='<%#library.GetDictionaryItem("ProfilePages_CVR nummer")%>'  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```